# How can I save this: " in a String

Tags: java

Yeah the title says all. How can I save this: " in a String. Because of the reason that you declare a String with ", you cant save this in a String directly. Is there another way?

Comment: `String s = "\"";` It is called 'escaping'.

Comment: Have you tried String a = "\"";?